# How to make Drupal upload pasted links to .doc files from the internet

Tags: 7, files

Let's say I have a Drupal website and I want there a function that would work like this:
Paste an URL to a .doc file, so on submit Drupal downloads that file, uploads to its local server and generates a link to download from the website.

I was wondering if this needs custom coding or can this be achieve with a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be achieved with [Filefield Sources](https://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) module.

> FileField Sources is an extension to the FileField module. The FileField module lets you upload files from your computer through a CCK field. The FileField Sources module expands on this ability by allowing you to select new or existing files through additional means, including:
>
> - Re-use files by an auto-complete textfield
> - Attach server-side files uploaded via FTP
> - **Transfer files from a remote server (cURL required)**
> - Paste a file directly from the clipboard (Drupal 7 only)
> - Select existing files through the IMCE file browser

Comment: If you put emphasis inside a quote, where it wasn't any in the original text, it's considered a nice and honest to note something like "emphasis mine" just after that quote.

Comment: Well I'm not that nice and I guess you lot will just have to live with my unnice and inconsiderately bolded text ;)